# QML newbie needing some help in hooking up C++ backend with QML frontend

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt-quick

I have code in C++ for saving and retrieving data from an XML file. I have some forms built in QML that I would like to hook up in such a way that when data is entered in my QML, processing is handled in C++, and searches are done for products via QML form, processed in C++ and list of product items are handed back to QML for display.

```
class ProcessRequests : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(string username READ username WRITE username)
    Q_PROPERTY(string useremail READ useremail WRITE useremail)
    Q_PROPERTY(string usercomplaint READ usercomplaint WRITE usercomplaint)


    public:

    ProcessRequests()
    {}
    ~ProcessRequests(){}

    Q_INVOKABLE void SubmitComplaint(){
     //TODO: Add Xml code to save the property values to file 

    }

};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is to inter-communicate between QML and C++ code, you can do it with code like this:

```
//Product.cpp
QmlApplicationViewer viewer;

QDeclarativeEngine *engine = viewer.engine();
QDeclarativeContext *context = engine->rootContext();

context->setContextProperty("Product", this);

//Your QML File
Product.YourFunction(args);
```

Comment: I applied the above but still seems I may be missing some other pieces please. Like How do I actually call this from my QML file?

Comment: This is an example of what you should do in the QML file:

Rectangle {
     id: button
     width: 100; height: 100

     MouseArea {
         anchors.fill: parent
   
   //This is the event that will call your c++ code
         onClicked: {
   //The name of the property you gave to the context object
   //and the name of the public function you wish to call
   Product.DoSomething("Hello there!");
   }
     }
 }

Answer (score 2):

The topic is rather large, you'd better have a look at the docs, they're quite clear and there should be some tutorial  as well. This is a good starting point: [QML bindings in C++](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qtbinding.html).

Comment: I have taken a look at that a couple of times and still coming up with not much on how exactly it is done or how much tweaking I need to do to my current data.